# RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED exception on getting Account List(Google My Business API)

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Nowadays we are implementing My Business api integration for our platform.
I followed this document "https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs" and after I trying to get account list an error occurred;

<HttpError 429 when requesting https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts?alt=json returned "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXX'.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'quota_metric': 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/default_requests', 'consumer': 'projects/XXXX', 'quota_limit': 'DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject', 'service': 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com'}}]">

```
 output = self.service.accounts().list().execute();
```

Anyone faced this type issue ?

Regards.

Comment: Hi hüseyin, did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, please mark it as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a rateLimiter:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
```

...

```
//requests per second
private static final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(5.0);
```

...

```
private static GenericJson executeWithRateLimiter(request,
            RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
   rateLimiter.acquire();
   return request.execute();
}
```